# How to do this using java expression language

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Let just say i have the following java object that I wish to read in my jsp using el:

```
class A {

 Map map = new HashMap();
 int count;

        String getAttribute(String attrName)
        {
                return map.get(attrName);
        }

       String getCount()
       { 
               return count;
      }

}
```

I can call count by doing `${a.count}`

But how How do I call the getAttribute using el ?

Answer (score 4):

Java EE 6 (e.g. Glassfish 3 would accept ${a.getAttribute('foo')}) supports method invocations, Java EE 5 doesn't. Here, you would need to expose your Map like this:

```
public Map getAttributes() {
  return map;
}
```

to make expression ${a.attributes['foo']}) work.

If you're outside Java EE/JSP, you could use an EE 6 compliant implementation like JUEL 2.2.x which supports method invocations.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot!

See the [guide](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) for what you can do and what not.

The reasoning behind this is that el is supposed to be a thin layer in your application that just gives access to data that sits behind pages for presentation purposes.

It should not replace the business logic of the application. While your **getAttribute** method is trivial enough several people could misuse it and convert it into a big fat method that performs a lot of stuff and has side-effects when it is run. This is exactly what el wants to avoid.

Comment: I'm more of the opinion that EL just wasn't thought through well enough. It's too simple in too many cases.

Comment: Note that if the method were named just "get()" then he could access it with as "a[someThing]".

Answer (score 2):

What you need is for your class to implement the [java.util.Map](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, simply by wrapping the internal map. Then you can use the following EL expression:

```
${a["attribute"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In El 2.x you can do the trick that David Rabinowitz said:

```
${a["attribute"]}
```